# How to @Ignore protected fields in Room library

Tags: android, android-room

Have an error with Room:

```
someField has protected access in LibraryClass
```

I have no access to this field, because it's in library. How can I force Room to not save this field(because I don't need it)?

Comment: I am not getting what exactly you want but `transient` keyword is actually you're looking for. give a try

Comment: @Aks4125 I have no access to LibraryClass. I want Room forget about this protected field. I don't want to save this field(Can't explain more clearly. Insufficient knowledge of English:( )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I force Room to not save this field

Don't inherit from that class. Having an `@Entity` inherit from some class that you do not control is fairly risky, and this is the sort of problem that you will encounter. Have your `@Entity` be a simple POJO.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your explanation